# Generating same information between multiple tabs in a spread sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel document that has 4 tabs in it.  How do I formulate cells in each of the tab spreadsheets to generate the same if I change the information on one.

Example:  Each tab spreadsheet has a cell that I input the employee's drivers license number.  if I update on one of the tab spreadsheet, I want it to update then on the other three tab spreadsheets.

Comment: Say you want the info in `A1` on all sheets. Before you enter the data, hold `CTRL` and click the sheet tabs, which will select multiple sheets at once. Then put the data in `A1`. It should put the info there on all selected sheets.  ...is that what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You can create references (I would guess that's what the comment from @brucewayne does, indirectly). This is a pretty good, basic tutorial:
http://www.techlineinfo.com/excel-formulas-for-linking-data-between-different-sheets/

You can use references by simply prefixing the cell name with the (source)sheet name, and a "!".
In the above 4-pages example: "**KeysSheet!A5**", would contain the DL#, assuming your "source" sheet/tab is called "KeysSheet".
It could be used across the other 3 tabs, effectively replicating the info, based on the source.
Relatively easy to use the reference this way, and it's reasonably self-documenting, as a plus.